# Question about community-accepted answers

Tags: support

How many votes an answer has to receive so to become accepted by the community?

Comment: @Annix were you asking about how a question becomes a "Community" question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community does not accept an answer, the person asking it does. Unfortunately, we have several people who don't bother or don't know that they should. The person asking the question will often use the number of votes to decide which answer to accept, so the community as a whole can use that to help influence an answer's chances of being selected.

Comment: A lot of folks just don't know about the accept button on their questions. For that reason, I try to gently instruct anyone I come across with a 0% accept.

Comment: @T.E.D. Showing the accept rate [was disabled in January](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate), mostly because most people weren't being as gentle as you (there were a couple of particularly nasty incidents and a _lot_ of borderline rude comments). Nevertheless, askers get periodically prompted by the system to consider accepting answers to their questions, and that's more than enough (imho). At the end of the day accepting an answer is strictly up to the OP, and on the more subjective sites I doubt the concept even makes sense.

Comment: IC. I guess that's probably for the best. I noticed quite a few folks with 100% rates, which seemed suspiciously high to me. Mine always tended to be around 60-75% (hey, I don't ask the easy questions.)